# Assign function/method to variable in Dart

Tags: dart

Does Dart support the concept of variable functions/methods? So to call a method by its name stored in a variable.

For example in PHP this can be done not only for methods:

```dart
// With functions...
function foo()
{
    echo 'Running foo...';
}

$function = 'foo';
$function();

// With classes...
public static function factory($view)
{
    $class = 'View_' . ucfirst($view);
    return new $class();
}
```

I did not found it in the language tour or API. Are others ways to do something like this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To store the name of a function in variable and call it later you will have to wait until reflection arrives in Dart (or [get creative](http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2012/04/playing-with-nosuchmethod-raises-some-questions/) with [noSuchMethod](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_core/Object.html#noSuchMethod)). You can however store functions directly in variables like in JavaScript

```dart
main() {
  var f = (String s) => print(s);
  f("hello world");
}
```

and even inline them, which come in handy if you are doing recusion:

```dart
main() {
   g(int i) {
      if(i > 0) {
         print("$i is larger than zero");
         g(i-1);
      } else {
         print("zero or negative");
      } 
   }
   g(10);
}
```

The functions stored can then be passed around to other functions

```dart
main() {
   var function;
   function = (String s) => print(s);
   doWork(function);
}

doWork(f(String s)) {
   f("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think it will help to solve my problem. Not thought about the Javascript way of storing functions in variables...

Answer (score 1):

I may not be the best explainer but you may consider this example to have a wider scope of the assigning functions to a variable and also using a closure function as a parameter of a function.

```
  void main() {
      // a closure function assigned to a variable.
      var fun = (int) => (int * 2); 
      // a variable which is assigned with the function which is written below
      var newFuncResult = newFunc(9, fun); 
      print(x); // Output: 27
    }

    //Below is a function with two parameter (1st one as int) (2nd as a closure function)
        int newFunc(int a, fun) {
          int x = a;
          int y = fun(x);
          return x + y;
        }
```

Comment: You're using `int` as a parameter name? Be careful.